# After upgrading from Ionic 4 app.component.ts is not firing at all

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, upgrade

I have upgraded my one year old Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4. After changing all navigation to routing I finally got the project to build, but when I run the application on the iPad simulator I just get a white screen after splash.

I build and launch the project correctly (worked in Ionic 3), but when I start the app I can only see the splash/log + a loader and then its goes white.

This is my app.components.ts file:

```
import ...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public platform: Platform,
                public fileSvc: FileStorageFactory,
                public weeksSvc: WeeksService,
                public activityTemplateService: ActivityTemplateService,
                public dataService: Data,
                private firestoreManager: FirestoreManager,
                private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                private statusBar: StatusBar,
                private globalization: Globalization,
                private router: Router
    ) {
        // THIS IS NOT FIRING...
        alert('AppComponent constructed');

        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // THIS IS NOT FIRING...
            alert('Success platform ready');

            ...

        }
    }

}
```

And this is my app.module.ts file:

```
import ...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AddSkypeUserPage,
        DagsVisningPage,
        HomePage,
        InnstillingerPage,
        LoginPage,
        NyAktivitetPage,
        CameraPopoverPage,
        ScoreboardPage,
        UkesplanleggerPage,
        DisclaimerModal,
        AccessCodePage
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        AppComponent,
        AddSkypeUserPage,
        DagsVisningPage,
        HomePage,
        InnstillingerPage,
        LoginPage,
        NyAktivitetPage,
        CameraPopoverPage,
        ScoreboardPage,
        UkesplanleggerPage,
        DisclaimerModal,
        AccessCodePage
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        LocalNotifications,
        Media,
        File,
        AppPreferences,
        Insomnia,
        FirestoreManager,
        Network,
        NetworkService,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

This is what I see in the stack trace in Xcode when running the app:

```
2020-01-03 17:44:12.660993+0100 XXX DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/otjorfald/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A0A52D9-56F3-428A-BF20-55C0D90E0A55/data/Containers/Data/Application/BF5494AB-0F5B-47CC-A0E1-C31CFA924044/Library/Cookies/com.ionicframework.eplanv2312693.binarycookies
2020-01-03 17:44:12.673073+0100 XXX Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
2020-01-03 17:44:12.673326+0100 XXX Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-01-03 17:44:12.699350+0100 XXX CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2020-01-03 17:44:12.817500+0100 XXX CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-01-03 17:44:12.817614+0100 XXX Using Ionic WKWebView
2020-01-03 17:44:12.817901+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][console] 0.039935ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.818043+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.057936ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.819302+0100 XXX Unlimited access to network resources
2020-01-03 17:44:12.819408+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.291990ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.819522+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.034928ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.835116+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][file] 15.504003ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.835411+0100 XXX CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2020-01-03 17:44:12.835988+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 0.741005ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.836127+0100 XXX DisableShakeToEdit plugin initialized.
2020-01-03 17:44:12.836229+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][disableshaketoedit] 0.154018ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.837812+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 1.502037ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.838907+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][statusbar] 0.995994ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.839440+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.424027ms
2020-01-03 17:44:12.839538+0100 XXX [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 21.691084ms
2020-01-03 17:44:13.802934+0100 XXX Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 314 ms
2020-01-03 17:44:13.803125+0100 XXX DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 238 ms
```

The AppComponent constructor is not running at all... I can also debug the webview in safari, and the elements I see is this (seems like its not able to map anything to app-root, since its empty): 
[image: Screenshot of elements in DOM]

My app-routing.module.ts:

```
import ...

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '/home', component: HomePage},
    {path: '/accessCode', component: AccessCodePage},
    {path: '/dagsVisning', component: DagsVisningPage},
    {path: '/innstillinger', component: InnstillingerPage},
    {path: '/login', component: LoginPage},
    {path: '/nyAktivitet', component: NyAktivitetPage},
    {path: '/scoreboard', component: ScoreboardPage},
    {path: '/ukesplanlegger', component: UkesplanleggerPage},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong or missing...?

All help appreciated! :)

Comment: can you share your router module? seems like initial routing is not happening

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Done. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: lets see:) ty for sharing so can you also share accessCodeGuard - your default page is subject to that guard and something prevents it from allowing to load.

Comment: I removed the guard and still its only white screen. But Shouldn't the app.components.ts 'platform.ready' fire before the routing anyway?

I dont get any respons from anything. Seems like the app is not able to connect or launch the ts part of the app or something...?

Comment: Seems like it may have something to do with my pages not being in the new format...